# Is there an object like `this` for modules?

Tags: javascript, module

The global object has various aliases: `this`, `frames`, `window`, etc. Is there such a name for the scope in the current module?

I would like to be able to do the following:

```js
import * as my_module from "/my/module.js";

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(my_module)) {
    module[key] = value;
    // Elevate `key` to module scope
}
```

Comment: "*// Elevate `key` to module scope*" but **why** are you doing this? What is your end goal?

Comment: I want to `import * as an_object from "/my/module.js"` and then use those imports without the `an_object` qualifier.

Comment: But I am also just curious.

Comment: Then you're not asking for how to "assign them to the global object" - that will just allow you to reference these keys from within the module as sort of "global" ones for the file. Although maybe that also means that you want to access these keys *globally* from any files which `global` does in Node.js. However, seems you're actually asking how to "export dynamically". These are completely different questions, which is why it's crucial to ask the correct one.

Comment: "... to reference these keys from within the module as sort of "global" ones for the file" -- This is exactly what I want.

Comment: that's not at all apparent in the question. Also, it's in conflict with the comment you had earlier: "*I want to import * as an_object from "/my/module.js" and then use those imports without the an_object qualifier*" - that is *not* referencing then as globals in the file, that's *exporting them* from the module.

Comment: Check my edit. `/my/module.js` is another file.